# objective-c SocketIO client cannot connect to gevent-socketIO server

Tags: objective-c, websocket, socket.io, gevent-socketio, django-socketio

I am using object-c socketio(https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) to connect to my gevent-socketIO server, which works fine with my webpage.

**CLIENT**

```
[self.socketIO connectToHost:SOCKET_URL onPort:SOCKET_PORT];
```

**SERVER**

```
def socketio(request):
    logger.info("Connecting start")
    socketio_manage(
        request.environ,
        {'': BigSpoonNamespace, },
        request=request
    )
    logger.info("Connecting finish")
    return HttpResponse()
```

**DJANGO LOG**

> ```
> 2014-01-25 18:21:01,499 [DEBUG] socketio.virtsocket: Spawning sub-Socket Greenlet: send_into_ws
> 2014-01-25 18:21:01,500 [DEBUG] socketio.virtsocket: Spawning sub-Socket Greenlet: read_from_ws
> 2014-01-25 18:21:01,500 [DEBUG] socketio.virtsocket: Spawning sub-Socket Greenlet: _heartbeat
> 2014-01-25 18:21:01,500 [DEBUG] socketio.virtsocket: Spawning sub-Socket Greenlet: _heartbeat_timeout
> 2014-01-25 18:21:01,502 [INFO] root: Connecting start
> 2014-01-25 18:22:01,525 [DEBUG] socketio.virtsocket: heartbeat timed out, killing socket
> 2014-01-25 18:22:01,526 [DEBUG] socketio.virtsocket: Removing sessid='64962840572' client_queue[1] server_queue[1] hits=1 from
> ```
>
> server sockets
>       2014-01-25 18:22:01,542 [INFO] root: Connecting finish

**NGINX LOG**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/webapps/2013-final-project-7/src/backend/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/webapps/2013-final-project-7/src/backend/env/src/gevent-socketio-master/socketio/transports.py", line 259, in read_from_ws
    message = websocket.receive()
  File "/home/ec2-user/webapps/2013-final-project-7/src/backend/env/src/gevent-websocket-master/geventwebsocket/websocket.py", line 296, in receive
    result = self._receive()
  File "/home/ec2-user/webapps/2013-final-project-7/src/backend/env/src/gevent-websocket-master/geventwebsocket/websocket.py", line 273, in _receive
    raise WebSocketError('Received invalid close frame: %r %r' % (code, self.close_message))
WebSocketError: Received invalid close frame: 65535 bytearray(b'')
<Greenlet at 0x3340550: read_from_ws> failed with WebSocketError
```

So what's wrong here?

On the cliend

```
- (void) socketIODidConnect:(SocketIO *)socket{}
```

never get invoked.
And the program always jump to the following after a few seconds.

```
- (void) socketIODidDisconnect:(SocketIO *)socket disconnectedWithError:(NSError *)error{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bummer!! My SocketIO.m and SRWebSocket.m File is modified to fix something warnings and obviously this breaks socketIO code... After use the original file, the issue is resolved. Now I want to slam my face to the keyboard..